# Error: "module does not exist" after I removed a module from the file system without disabling and uninstalling it

Tags: 8, database, installation

I removed a module from the file system without disabling and uninstalling it. And now I have error:

**Drupal\Core\Extension\Exception\UnknownExtensionException: The module drupalweather does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionList->getPathname() (line 522 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionList.php).**

How to solve this error? 
I use **windows operating system** and local server **open server**.

Comment: It's fairly straight forward - put the files back and then uninstall it before deleting again

Comment: Make sure it's uninstalled from all environments before you remove it from the codebase. I.e. **do not** uninstall locally, then delete, then push those changes up to another server.

Answer (score 2):

@Leigh comment:

> It's fairly straight forward - put the files back and then uninstall
> it before deleting again

### Solved the error